# Spring Stomp websockets error stompWebSocketHandlerMapping

Tags: spring

I want to communicate through sockets for my web app (spring). I was following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring) documentation but I get this error. What is the problem?
Error creating bean with name 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for anyone getting this error, I replaced these dependecies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with this:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```